# idHttp Get + Delphi + The requested URL was rejected

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

I'm trying to run this code:

```
var
  objHttp: TIdHTTP;
...
  objHttp.HandleRedirects := True;
  objHttp.AllowCookies := True;
  sGet := objHttp.Get('http://www.bmf.com.br/arquivos1/arquivos_ipn.asp?idioma=pt-BR&status=ativo');
...
```

and I'm getting this:

```html
<code>
   <html>
      <head>
         <title>Request Rejected</title>
      </head>
      <body>The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.<br>Your support ID is: 109088803187671168</body>
   </html>
</code>
```

any idea why?

Comment: Set `objHttp.Request.UserAgent` to some web browser user agent. That server does not like the Indy's default one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution, thanks to TLama:

```
var
  objHttp: TIdHTTP;
  ...
  objHttp.HandleRedirects := True;
  objHttp.AllowCookies := True;
  objHttp.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0';
  sGet := objHttp.Get('http://www.bmf.com.br/arquivos1/arquivos_ipn.asp?idioma=pt-BR&status=ativo');
  ...
```